# имя не существует в контексте

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Использую selenium с c#. Необходимо сделать ожидание. Хочу использовать такую конструкцию:

```
WebDriverWait ww = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1001));
IWebElement lnks = ww.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.ClassName("some_class")));
```

VS2017 подчеркивает ExpectedConditions красным и пишет "имя ExpectedConditions не существует в текущем контексте". Все нужные юзинги на месте:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using static OpenQA.Selenium.By;
using static OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait;
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что сделать, чтоб не ругалось

Непосредственное добавление:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если дописать этот Namespace? `OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.ExpectedConditions.....`

Comment: Все равно проблемы

Comment: Я не про using говорю, а про `ww.Until(OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.ClassName("some_class")));`, прям в вызове допишите от куда хотите взять этот класс и посмотрите что вам предложит студия.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо было добавить Nuget пакет. У меня студия 17 на русском, поэтому средства -> диспетчер пакетов Nuget -> управление пакетами для решения -> забиваем в поиске selenium support и ставим